# Ag-grid Master/Detail component change height

Tags: ag-grid

I need to change height of Master/Detail row while expanded i.e. after clicking on some button. I got to the point where I set new height like `this.gridOptions.detailRowHeight = 100;`. I just don't know how should I refresh grid to display master/detail with changed height. I tried `api.resetRowHeights()`, but it seems to be only affecting 'parent' rows, not expanded ones (master/detail).

Comment: Maybe post your html and js-code. Without it it's rather hard to unterstand exactly what you are trying to do and what needs to be done.

Comment: can you try this.gridOptions.rowHeight = 100 to change height of all rows?

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.